# Dapper's [ExplicitKey] attribute - what's the purpose?

Tags: dapper

What is the purpose of Dapper's **[ExplicitKey]** attribute?
In [this example](http://dapper-tutorial.net/data-annotation-explicitkey) generated SQL is absolutely identical, regardless of whether the key is applied or not.

```
exec sp_executesql 
N'insert into InvoiceDetail ([InvoiceID], [Detail]) values (@InvoiceID, @Detail);
select SCOPE_IDENTITY() id',N'@Detail nvarchar(4000),@InvoiceID int',@Detail=N'Insert_Single_1',@InvoiceID=4
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is why the attribute exists:

https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/351

The [Key] attribute assumes an autoincremented key, and when you try to pass a custom (e.g. non-int) key instead, Insert and InsertAsync fail with NullReferenceException, even if the passed value clearly isn't null. So [ExplicitKey] was introduced to handle those instead.